# How to use IF EXISTS in the INSERT operation of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am using MYSQL (v5.8). I have a large table `myTab` that has lot of columns. "name" and "batch_date" are the columns I need to update on daily basis.

I tried below SP to avoid duplicate entries for particular date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.`sp_name`() 
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (Select * from dbname.myTab where batch_date=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval 1 day) 
BEGIN 
delete from myTab where batch_date=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval 1) END;
ELSE
INSERT INTO dbname.myTab(name,batch_date) SELECT name,
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) from
dbname.myAnotherTab; 
END IF; 
END;
```

But I'm getting MySQL syntax error at IF EXISTS part. I tried with IF EXISTS ... THEN ... too, but of no use. Could someone give me a solution for this.

Comment: Try if(Select 1 from qa_main.retailer where batch_date=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval 1 day group by 1) = 1